# Why does iOS 11 IKEv2 VPN lack Send All Traffic option?

Tags: ios, vpn

I'm trying this on iOS 11.2 iPad.

- L2TP VPN has "Send All Traffic" option, so that I can control whether I would use VPN server as my default Internet gateway.
- Curiously, IKEv2 VPN does not have that option, and I find it works like "Send All Traffic = yes".

Could someone explain why **Send All Traffic** option for IKEv2 is missing from Apple's design?

[image: iOS 11.3, L2TP vs IKEv2]

Using Windows 7 as IKEv2 VPN client, the client machine can surely have control of this option.